# Loading progressbar similar to Play Books/Newsstand

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, loading, android-progressbar

Im using an Intentservice to load data in the background which I then show in a fragment. While its loading I show a ProgressDialog but I would prefer something that looks like the "loadingscreen" the google apps use.

Just a blank screen with a progressbar in the middle.

What would be the best way to implement something like that?

Just a layout with the progress and then inflate the "real" layout when the Service is done loading? Or is there a way to overlay something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a custom Fragment that I open when the service starts loading and close when its done.

I tried to use a Dialog but it covered the Actionbar too and I wasnt able to get it to the size of the "contentframe" only.